# Refreshing listview in bottom sheet

Tags: listview

I ran into a problem
I created a bottom sheet
And created a listview programatically in it and added it to linear1 in that bottom sheet
Now the problem is
I have created Listview1Adapter class

And when i try to refresh the listview from its adapter
i.e

`public class Listview1Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

//other methods

((BaseAdapter)listview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged);
}`

It gives me an error listview1 cannot be resolved

What is the solution to it
I must have to refresh my listview in order to keep my app work fine

I tried chatGPT but it's just giving me the same not working solution
I also searched for it on google
Asked some of my friends on telegram
But nothing worked
Now i only have a hope that Stack over flow will help mee

Thanks allot
Luv you all

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and tag a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for nothing lol.
By the way i found the solution to this problem

First of all in bottom sheet initialize the listview
i.e

```
`ListView  listview1 = (ListView)layBase.findViewById(R.id.listview1);`
```

Then

`listview1.setAdapter(new Listview1Adapter(arrayList));`

Now change the code

((BaseAdapter)listview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

To

`notifyDataSetChanged();`

Its that simple

I am sorry i just have lack of knowledge.
As it was a stupid question

Thanks